# Jquery setinterval refreshed ajax function breaks dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jquery that refreshes values from datatable every second with the below code which breaks dropdown

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     fetch_coinprices()

     setInterval(function(){
     fetch_coinprices() // this will run after every 5 seconds
}, 1000);


 function fetch_coinprices()
 {
  
 }



});
```

```html
//Dropdown
<li class="nav-item dropdown header-profile">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <img src="{{ asset('images/profile/G-logo.png') }}" width="20" alt=""/>
                            <div class="header-info">
                                <span id='userid'>{{ Auth::id() }}</span>
                                <small>Admin</small>
                            </div>
                        </a>
            </li>
```

When it refreshes the datatable with ajax every second, it causes some issues on the page.

Like when you go for a dropdown(data-toggle="dropdown") it stops it and you have to open it again since every 1 second you cant operate.

Of course, as a workaround, I can increase the time but I would appreciate it if you have a more elegant way to handle this issue?

Comment: If the dropdowns are part of what you are replacing there (the innerHTML of the table body), then there probably is no other solution than to "pause" your one second interval, as long as the user is interacting with one of the dropdown fields.

Comment: I've simplified the snippets and added an example dropdowns that being effected.

Comment: That is not so much "simplified", as rather bereft of any meaning now.

Comment: I noticed that it was caused by another included ajax which is very complex for me to fix so I just removed it entirely :) thanks @CBroe